# Java textfield autocomplete

Tags: java, mysql

This is my code and i am getting the error below can anyone help? it was wroking fine but i dont know what happend suddenly...

basically there are two textboxes 1st is getting value from that list mentioned and other is getting values from database 1st one is working fine...
the problem is when i try to write anything in 2nd txtfield its giving this error

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;


public class Test {
static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/timetable?useSSL=false";

    //  Database credentials

    public Test() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextField tftea = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField f = new JTextField(20);
        AutoSuggestor semtea = new AutoSuggestor(tftea, frame, null, Color.WHITE.brighter(), Color.BLUE, Color.RED,
                0.75f) {
            @Override
            boolean wordTyped(String typedWord) {
                ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
                    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT program FROM `sem`");
                    ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

                    while (result.next()) {
                        // comboBoxName.addItem(result.getString("teacher"));
                        String a = result.getString("program");
                        words.add(a);
                        System.out.println(a);
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                setDictionary(words);
                return super.wordTyped(typedWord);// now call super to check for
                                                    // any matches against
                                                    // newest dictionary
            }
        };

        AutoSuggestor autoSuggestor = new AutoSuggestor(f, frame, null, Color.WHITE.brighter(), Color.BLUE, Color.RED, 0.75f) {
            @Override
            boolean wordTyped(String typedWord) {

                //create list for dictionary this in your case might be done via calling a method which queries db and returns results as arraylist
                ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
                words.add("hello");
                words.add("heritage");
                words.add("happiness");
                words.add("goodbye");
                words.add("cruel");
                words.add("car");
                words.add("war");
                words.add("will");
                words.add("world");
                words.add("wall");


                setDictionary(words);
                //addToDictionary("bye");//adds a single word

                return super.wordTyped(typedWord);//now call super to check for any matches against newest dictionary
            }
        };

        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        p.add(f);
        p.add(tftea);
        frame.add(p);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}

class AutoSuggestor {

    private final JTextField textField;
    private final Window container;
    private JPanel suggestionsPanel;
    private JWindow autoSuggestionPopUpWindow;
    private String typedWord;
    private final ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
    private int currentIndexOfSpace, tW, tH;
    private DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            checkForAndShowSuggestions();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            checkForAndShowSuggestions();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            checkForAndShowSuggestions();
        }
    };
    private final Color suggestionsTextColor;
    private final Color suggestionFocusedColor;

    public AutoSuggestor(JTextField textField, Window mainWindow, ArrayList<String> words, Color popUpBackground, Color textColor, Color suggestionFocusedColor, float opacity) {
        this.textField = textField;
        this.suggestionsTextColor = textColor;
        this.container = mainWindow;
        this.suggestionFocusedColor = suggestionFocusedColor;
        this.textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);

        setDictionary(words);

        typedWord = "";
        currentIndexOfSpace = 0;
        tW = 0;
        tH = 0;

        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow = new JWindow(mainWindow);
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setOpacity(opacity);

        suggestionsPanel = new JPanel();
        suggestionsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        suggestionsPanel.setBackground(popUpBackground);

        addKeyBindingToRequestFocusInPopUpWindow();
    }

    private void addKeyBindingToRequestFocusInPopUpWindow() {
        textField.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "Down released");
        textField.getActionMap().put("Down released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {//focuses the first label on popwindow
                for (int i = 0; i < suggestionsPanel.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                    if (suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i) instanceof SuggestionLabel) {
                        ((SuggestionLabel) suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i)).setFocused(true);
                        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.toFront();
                        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.requestFocusInWindow();
                        suggestionsPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
                        suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i).requestFocusInWindow();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        suggestionsPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "Down released");
        suggestionsPanel.getActionMap().put("Down released", new AbstractAction() {
            int lastFocusableIndex = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {//allows scrolling of labels in pop window (I know very hacky for now :))

                ArrayList<SuggestionLabel> sls = getAddedSuggestionLabels();
                int max = sls.size();

                if (max > 1) {//more than 1 suggestion
                    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                        SuggestionLabel sl = sls.get(i);
                        if (sl.isFocused()) {
                            if (lastFocusableIndex == max - 1) {
                                lastFocusableIndex = 0;
                                sl.setFocused(false);
                                autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setVisible(false);
                                setFocusToTextField();
                                checkForAndShowSuggestions();//fire method as if document listener change occured and fired it

                            } else {
                                sl.setFocused(false);
                                lastFocusableIndex = i;
                            }
                        } else if (lastFocusableIndex <= i) {
                            if (i < max) {
                                sl.setFocused(true);
                                autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.toFront();
                                autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.requestFocusInWindow();
                                suggestionsPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
                                suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i).requestFocusInWindow();
                                lastFocusableIndex = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {//only a single suggestion was given
                    autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setVisible(false);
                    setFocusToTextField();
                    checkForAndShowSuggestions();//fire method as if document listener change occured and fired it
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setFocusToTextField() {
        container.toFront();
        container.requestFocusInWindow();
        textField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public ArrayList<SuggestionLabel> getAddedSuggestionLabels() {
        ArrayList<SuggestionLabel> sls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < suggestionsPanel.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            if (suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i) instanceof SuggestionLabel) {
                SuggestionLabel sl = (SuggestionLabel) suggestionsPanel.getComponent(i);
                sls.add(sl);
            }
        }
        return sls;
    }

    private void checkForAndShowSuggestions() {
        typedWord = getCurrentlyTypedWord();

        suggestionsPanel.removeAll();//remove previos words/jlabels that were added

        //used to calcualte size of JWindow as new Jlabels are added
        tW = 0;
        tH = 0;

        boolean added = wordTyped(typedWord);

        if (!added) {
            if (autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.isVisible()) {
                autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setVisible(false);
            }
        } else {
            showPopUpWindow();
            setFocusToTextField();
        }
    }

    protected void addWordToSuggestions(String word) {
        SuggestionLabel suggestionLabel = new SuggestionLabel(word, suggestionFocusedColor, suggestionsTextColor, this);

        calculatePopUpWindowSize(suggestionLabel);

        suggestionsPanel.add(suggestionLabel);
    }

    public String getCurrentlyTypedWord() {//get newest word after last white spaceif any or the first word if no white spaces
        String text = textField.getText();
        String wordBeingTyped = "";
        if (text.contains(" ")) {
            int tmp = text.lastIndexOf(" ");
            if (tmp >= currentIndexOfSpace) {
                currentIndexOfSpace = tmp;
                wordBeingTyped = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(" "));
            }
        } else {
            wordBeingTyped = text;
        }
        return wordBeingTyped.trim();
    }

    private void calculatePopUpWindowSize(JLabel label) {
        //so we can size the JWindow correctly
        if (tW < label.getPreferredSize().width) {
            tW = label.getPreferredSize().width;
        }
        tH += label.getPreferredSize().height;
    }

    private void showPopUpWindow() {
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.getContentPane().add(suggestionsPanel);
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(textField.getWidth(), 30));
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setSize(tW, tH);
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setVisible(true);

        int windowX = 0;
        int windowY = 0;

        windowX = container.getX() + textField.getX() + 5;
        if (suggestionsPanel.getHeight() > autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.getMinimumSize().height) {
            windowY = container.getY() + textField.getY() + textField.getHeight() + autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.getMinimumSize().height;
        } else {
            windowY = container.getY() + textField.getY() + textField.getHeight() + autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.getHeight();
        }

        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setLocation(windowX, windowY);
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(textField.getWidth(), 30));
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.revalidate();
        autoSuggestionPopUpWindow.repaint();

    }

    public void setDictionary(ArrayList<String> words) {
        dictionary.clear();
        if (words == null) {
            return;//so we can call constructor with null value for dictionary without exception thrown
        }
        for (String word : words) {
            dictionary.add(word);
        }
    }

    public JWindow getAutoSuggestionPopUpWindow() {
        return autoSuggestionPopUpWindow;
    }

    public Window getContainer() {
        return container;
    }

    public JTextField getTextField() {
        return textField;
    }

    public void addToDictionary(String word) {
        dictionary.add(word);
    }

    boolean wordTyped(String typedWord) {

        if (typedWord.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        //System.out.println("Typed word: " + typedWord);

        boolean suggestionAdded = false;

        for (String word : dictionary) {//get words in the dictionary which we added
            boolean fullymatches = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < typedWord.length(); i++) {//each string in the word
                if (!typedWord.toLowerCase().startsWith(String.valueOf(word.toLowerCase().charAt(i)), i)) {//check for match
                    fullymatches = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (fullymatches) {
                addWordToSuggestions(word);
                suggestionAdded = true;
            }
        }
        return suggestionAdded;
    }
}

class SuggestionLabel extends JLabel {

    private boolean focused = false;
    private final JWindow autoSuggestionsPopUpWindow;
    private final JTextField textField;
    private final AutoSuggestor autoSuggestor;
    private Color suggestionsTextColor, suggestionBorderColor;

    public SuggestionLabel(String string, final Color borderColor, Color suggestionsTextColor, AutoSuggestor autoSuggestor) {
        super(string);

        this.suggestionsTextColor = suggestionsTextColor;
        this.autoSuggestor = autoSuggestor;
        this.textField = autoSuggestor.getTextField();
        this.suggestionBorderColor = borderColor;
        this.autoSuggestionsPopUpWindow = autoSuggestor.getAutoSuggestionPopUpWindow();

        initComponent();
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        setFocusable(true);
        setForeground(suggestionsTextColor);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                super.mouseClicked(me);

                replaceWithSuggestedText();

                autoSuggestionsPopUpWindow.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, true), "Enter released");
        getActionMap().put("Enter released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                replaceWithSuggestedText();
                autoSuggestionsPopUpWindow.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setFocused(boolean focused) {
        if (focused) {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(suggestionBorderColor));
        } else {
            setBorder(null);
        }
        repaint();
        this.focused = focused;
    }

    public boolean isFocused() {
        return focused;
    }

    private void replaceWithSuggestedText() {
        String suggestedWord = getText();
        String text = textField.getText();
        String typedWord = autoSuggestor.getCurrentlyTypedWord();
        String t = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(typedWord));
        String tmp = t + text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(typedWord)).replace(typedWord, suggestedWord);
        textField.setText(tmp + " ");
    }
}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at timetable.AutoSuggestor.wordTyped(Test.java:360)
    at timetable.Test$1.wordTyped(Test.java:64)
    at timetable.AutoSuggestor.checkForAndShowSuggestions(Test.java:256)
    at timetable.AutoSuggestor.access$0(Test.java:247)
    at timetable.AutoSuggestor$1.insertUpdate(Test.java:127)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.replace(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.replaceSelection(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit$DefaultKeyTypedAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this is the code which is creating problem

```
public void addToDictionary(String word) {
    dictionary.add(word);
}

boolean wordTyped(String typedWord) {

    if (typedWord.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    //System.out.println("Typed word: " + typedWord);

    boolean suggestionAdded = false;

    for (String word : dictionary) {//get words in the dictionary which we added
        boolean fullymatches = true;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < typedWord.length(); ii++) {//each string in the word
            if (!typedWord.toLowerCase().startsWith(String.valueOf(word.toLowerCase().charAt(ii)), ii)) {//check for match
                fullymatches = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (fullymatches) {
            addWordToSuggestions(word);
            suggestionAdded = true;
        }
    }
    return suggestionAdded;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you reduce your code to the wordTyped() method that has the exception? StringIndexOutOfBoundsException means chatAt tries to read more characters than are inside the string, like the 4th letter in "cat".

Comment: Thanks for your reply i have updated my questions. and i don't understand why it is giving error for database code only

Comment: also, i have executed query separately its working fine

Comment: its giving me error on first character i write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code breaking is:

```
if (!typedWord.toLowerCase().startsWith(String.valueOf(word.toLowerCase().charAt(ii)), ii))
```

so if

```
typedWord = "household"
word = "house"
```

then for ii = 5 the code will try to read the 6th character of typedWord and word, causing the exception because "house" has only 5 characters.

Maybe you have an empty word in the database.

Comment: this query is returning words like BBA, BCS, MBA but its giving error after entering 1 char such as if i enter b before writing other characters

Comment: i'm sorry if i sound stupid but if it would have had string in dictionary then it should give me error when i'am calling it from 1st textfield? see from
class AutoSuggestor below all te code is called by both text fields why it is giving error for 2nd only?

Comment: One dictionary is from code. There is no empty string in the code. The other dictionary comes from DB.  There is an empty string in the DB. So the code works with code-directory but not with db-directory.

Comment: yes you were right :) Thank you i have written condition to not to add empty string in list. i just want to know is there any way to find out why database is giving me one extra empty string?

Comment: remove the large complete program from this question if not needed. To debug the database run SQL queries against it, like `SELECT * FROM sem where program = ''`